# Major problem with Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Since I decided to use Ubuntu -yesterday- I've been struggling with the drivers. It isn't recognizing my optical disc drive nor my video card, a Nvidia 8500gt. For the matter, here's how I "successfully" installed the `.run` driver downloaded from Nvidia's website:

The terminal wouldn't let me start the installation because the X server had to be shutdown, so I pressed `Ctrl+Alt+F1`

Then, I used:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
cd /(directory where the nvidiaupdate.run was)
chmod +x nvidiaupdate.run
sudo ./nvidiaupdate.run
```

The installation began and got completed, but unfortunately it crashed Ubuntu's UI, invalidating the OS for me. All that would appear was a DOS-like screen with reports. I'm new to Linux, so I really would appreciate any help given. For now, I'm sticking to the additional drivers, but even with it Ubuntu doesn't show my video card in the informations of the system.

Forgive my bad English.

Comment: You probably shouldn't install nvidia drivers by hand: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-a-graphics-or-wireless-card-driver

Answer (score 1):

Could you tell us what version of ubuntu you are using and if it is  32 or 64-bit please?

Also check if you downloaded the right driver. It should be the 290.10 Linux 32-bit/Linux 64-bit released on november 22nd 2011.

Comment: I just searched the ubuntuforums.org page for your problem...apparently a lot of people are having issues with this and I could not find a definite fix for it. There are a lot of suggestions though...one says you should try installing ubuntu from the alternate install CD...Another important thing to know: Can you access your system or do you get a black screen during boot?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm using Ubuntu 64-bit 11.10. Unfortunately, I can't access the system unless I get rid of Nvidia's drivers, for which only a black screen appears during boot. I don't recommend installing the drivers "manually", especially because I had to reinstall Ubuntu via USB to fix the problem -the easiest alternative I found. The additional drivers allow me to use the video card - I can easily play steam games-, but it seems I'll have problems overclocking it.